# How to render Bootstrap 4 table on small devices?

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, media-queries, bootstrap-table

I have an bootstrap 4 table which i am populating  with some JSON data,my table is rendering perfectly on `UI`,but on small device user have to scroll to see the full table data , although the HTML table doesn't have that much of data that user should scroll on small device.

1. What i am trying to achieve,on mobile screen the table data should come on full screen
2. there is no need for user to scroll horizontally if there is less then `8` or `10` columns in a table
3. Here i have a Bootstrap HTML table with only 6 columns that should come on `UI` of small screen like mobile phones on one go, but its not.

**Snippet**

```js
var data = [{
    "amount": 518212,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 104801,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 138151,
    "billdate": "2018-08-04",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 628358,
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 115223,
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 134107,
    "billdate": "2018-08-05",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 177866,
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 66095,
    "billdate": "2018-08-06",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 284069,
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 58789,
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "MALLESHWARAM"
  },
  {
    "amount": 67886,
    "billdate": "2018-08-07",
    "outlet": "KOLAR"
  },
  {
    "amount": 518212,
    "billdate": "2018-08-08",
    "outlet": "JAYANAGAR1"
  },



]
let formatData = function(data) {
  let billdates = [];
  let outlets = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    if (billdates.indexOf(element.billdate) == -1) {
      billdates.push(element.billdate);
    }
    if (outlets.indexOf(element.outlet) == -1) {
      outlets.push(element.outlet);
    }
  });
  return {
    data: data,
    billdates: billdates,
    outlets: outlets,
  };
};
let renderTable = function(data) {
  billdates = data.billdates;
  outlets = data.outlets;
  data = data.data;
  let tbl = document.getElementById("tblOlSalesSummary");
  let table = document.createElement("table");
  let thead = document.createElement("thead");
  let headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  let th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "BillDate";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  let grandTotal = 0;
  let outletWiseTotal = {};
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = element;
    th.classList.add("text-center");
    headerRow.appendChild(th);
    outletWiseTotal[element] = 0;
    data.forEach(el => {
      if (el.outlet == element) {
        outletWiseTotal[element] += parseInt(el.amount);
      }
    });
    grandTotal += outletWiseTotal[element];
  });
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  headerRow = document.createElement("tr");
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = "Total";
  th.classList.add("text-center");
  headerRow.appendChild(th);
  outlets.forEach(element => {
    th = document.createElement("th");
    th.innerHTML = outletWiseTotal[element].toLocaleString('en-in');
    th.classList.add("text-right");

    headerRow.appendChild(th);
  });
  th = document.createElement("th");
  th.innerHTML = grandTotal.toLocaleString('en-in');
  th.classList.add("text-right");
  headerRow.insertBefore(th, headerRow.children[1]);
  thead.appendChild(headerRow);
  table.appendChild(thead);

  let tbody = document.createElement("tbody");
  billdates.forEach(element => {
    let row = document.createElement("tr");
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = element;
    row.appendChild(td);
    let total = 0;
    outlets.forEach(outlet => {
      let el = 0;
      data.forEach(d => {
        if (d.billdate == element && d.outlet == outlet) {
          total += parseInt(d.amount);
          el = d.amount;
        }
      });
      td = document.createElement("td");
      td.innerHTML = el.toLocaleString('en-in');
      td.classList.add("text-right");
      row.appendChild(td);
    });
    /* console.log("row is : " , row.children ) */
    td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = total.toLocaleString('en-in');
    td.classList.add("text-right");
    // row.appendChild(td);
    row.insertBefore(td, row.children[1]);
    tbody.appendChild(row);
  });

  table.appendChild(tbody);
  tbl.innerHTML = "";
  tbl.appendChild(table);
  table.classList.add("table");
  table.classList.add("table-hover");
  table.classList.add("table-bordered");

}
let formatedData = formatData(data);
renderTable(formatedData);
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1500px) {
  table.table-bordered>thead>tr>th {
    border: 1px solid black;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 15pt;
  }
  table.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    white-space: nowrap;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 12pt;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  table.table-bordered>thead>tr>th {
    font-size: 7pt;
  }
  table.table-bordered>tbody>tr>td {
    font-size: 5pt;
  }
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div align="center" class="table table-responsive">

  <table id="tblOlSalesSummary">
  </table>

</div>
```

Just want to populate the table on small device on one go so that user doesn't need to scroll horizontaly

Please check on small devices its scrolling horizontally for small data also which i don't want.

So any one out here please help me out that how can i render table on small device on one go on the full screen.

Comment: for removing border you have to remove the border from your table td tag, and to render the table in mobile you can try removing the mobile-responsive. but that will not help cause the table width is seems to be greater than actual viewport.

Comment: @Chilll007 i have removed the border,but just want to set the table on mobile on full viewport

Comment: i told you table will shrink to the width it can adjust, as your table is bigger than the viewport screen it will not fit in your screen and overflows. you can try to apply display: block to the td and th it will make them goes one by one. but that is not the proper solution. horizontal scroll is what is the proper solution for overflowing table.

Comment: @Chilll007 yupp you are right, i got your point,but i am using media queries so that for small device i can make the font size smaller but the change is not happening ,can you help me out in this

Comment: hi i cheked your snippet and the issue is your media query css is overriden by the another css try to override that css or you can use !important, also you an reduce the padding of the td and th tag that will also help you.. thanks

Comment: @Chilll007 i have remove that overridden css,but its not working, i am trying to give diff styles on diff devices please check...other changes it is taking,but  resizing `font-size` its not talking

Comment: I made some edits and seems that the font-size is working now for smaller screens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to put the table inside table.. you can use 1 table and populate data into that table.thanks

check below link

https://codepen.io/Xenio/pen/zyadrv?editors=1000`xxx`

Comment: that was not an issue,now after removing the table,the table render on full screen on large device,which is taking full width,and my main issue is to display the HTML table on small device without scrolling